# Is it possible to ssh to the server in Azure which has the Azure SQL database and execute bash commands in it?

Tags: bash, azure, ssh, azure-sql-database

I was wondering if it is possible to ssh to the server in Azure which has the Azure SQL database and execute bash commands in it.

Comment: No, the host of an Azure SQL Database can't be ssh'd to.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: **NO**.

Long answer:

```
 #     #                                    
 ##    #  ####   ####   ####   ####   ####  
 # #   # #    # #    # #    # #    # #    # 
 #  #  # #    # #    # #    # #    # #    # 
 #   # # #    # #    # #    # #    # #    # 
 #    ## #    # #    # #    # #    # #    # 
 #     #  ####   ####   ####   ####   ####
```